# Trying to call factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, mean.io

I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: MyTheme.register is not a function

Because I'm trying to call this function from my package from my controllers folder. I have tried:

```
vm.register = function() {
    MyTheme.register(this.user);
};
```

And I have also tried this:

```
vm.register = function() {
    MyTheme.prototype.register(this.user);
};
```

Both of my attempts didn't succeeded.

The function lives in my package located in services/myTheme.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.myTheme').factory('MyTheme', [
  function() {
    MeanUserKlass.prototype.register = function(user) {
      $http.post('/api/register', {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
        confirmPassword: user.confirmPassword,
        username: user.username,
        name: user.name
      })
        .success(this.onIdentity.bind(this))
        .error(this.onIdFail.bind(this));
    };

    return {
      name: 'myTheme'
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
var module = angular.module('MyModule');
module.factory('MyFactory', function () {
    return { // all of this will be available, when you inject MyFactory
        someFoo: function () {}
    }
});
module.controller('MyCtrl', ['MyFactory', function (MyFactory) {
    MyFactory.someFoo(); // available now
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the function in your return object or possibly simply return your MeanUserKlass object.  Here is an article that deals with factories and prototypes: http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2014/02/14/angularjs-services-inheritance/